ADX external tables fails, wrong managed identity
I am trying to create a new external table (kind=delta) in Azure Data Explorer.
My code is standard:
.create-or-alter external table external_someexport
(col1:int, col2:int, mydate:datetime )
kind=delta
( 
  h@'https://mystorageaccount.dfs.core.windows.net/mydir/;managed_identity=system)'
 )

Now I am getting a strange error pointing towards the use of managed identity:

 "code": "Internal service error",
    "message": "Request aborted due to an internal service error.",
    "@type": "Kusto.Common.Svc.Exceptions.InvalidStorageConnectionStringsManagedIdentityException",
    "@message": "Invalid storage connection strings. When using managed identity authentication, all connection strings must reference the same managed identity."


What does that error mean ? I cannot change the MI at all in the code as it is just managed_identity=system. All my other tables are using the managed_identity=system, too.

I had same error.  this fixed it for me.
if you have more than one policy in the array.
.show  database MYDB policy managed_identity  | project Policy

be sure you make a note of the AllowedUsages you require before deleting and recreate.
.delete database MYDB policy managed_identity  
   
.alter-merge database MYDB policy managed_identity  '[ { "ObjectId": "system", "AllowedUsages": "ExternalTable,AutomatedFlows" }]'
 


The error message you're seeing indicates that your external table references multiple connection strings, which not all use the same managed identity.
In the example you're providing, that error message should not be returned. Are you certain it's the same one that generated the error?
Thanks,
Shani
